# Kaggle Notebook does not Print Logs

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

my Kaggle-Notebook does not print Outputs.

```py
import logging
import sys

# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection,SpellCheckingInspection,SpellCheckingInspection,SpellCheckingInspection,PyArgumentList
def defaultLogger(name="fashiondataset", level=logging.DEBUG, handlers=None,
                  format='[%(asctime)s] {%(filename)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s'):
    handlers = handlers if handlers else [logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)]

    logging.basicConfig(level=level, format=format, handlers=handlers)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    logging.getLogger("matplotlib").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("nltk_data").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("pysndfx").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger('connectionpool').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    return logger
print("Testing Logger")
logger = defaultLogger()
logger.info("Logging Info Test")
logger.debug("Logging Debug Test")
logger.error("Logging Error Test")
print("Testing Logger [DONE]")
```

Output:

```
Testing Logger
Testing Logger [DONE]
```

I also tried to add `logging.getLogger(name).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` but it does not Change anything. TQDM / Tensorflow Progressbars are working.

Edit://
`sys.stdout.write("test")` Works